# Angular Material Button Toggle far bigger than normal button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

The situation is pretty simple I have a couple of buttons and button toggles:

```html
<button mat-raised-button style="margin-right: 8px">Active</button>

<mat-button-toggle [checked]="showOnlyActive" (change)="showOnlyActiveChanged($event.source.checked)" style="margin-right: 8px">Active</mat-button-toggle>
```

I expected them to have the same appearance, but for some reason button toggles are far bigger than normal buttons:

[image]

Is there a simple way to use the same size for button toggles as for normal buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `appearance="legacy"` input for the `mat-button-toggle-group` as shown here: https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/examples

Answer (score 1):

You have to add custom style to change line of the class **mat-button-toggle-label-content**

You can set your own height for example:

```
.mat-button-toggle-label-content {
    line-height: 24px !important;  
}
```

Here you can change your height according to your needs.